# How will I set the BitmapDrawable into the ImageView?

Tags: android, image, imageview, save

The `tapimageview` is the `ImageView` that I want to show the `mBitmapDrawable` once I click the save image. Am I doing the right thing?

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Save Tab Clicked");
            viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);//i is imageview whch u want to convert in bitmap
            canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
            tapimageview.draw(canvas);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(drawingBitmap, matrix, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmpstickers, matrix, paint);
            try {
                mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBitmap);
                tapimageview.setImageMatrix(mBitmapDrawable);
                mCurrent = "PXD_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".jpg";

                mNewSaving = ((BitmapDrawable) mBitmapDrawable).getBitmap();
                String FtoSave = mTempDir + mCurrent;
                File mFile = new File(FtoSave);
                mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutputStream);
                mFileOutputStream.flush();
                mFileOutputStream.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "FileNotFoundExceptionError " + e.toString());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "IOExceptionError " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the error is this tapimageview.setImageMatrix(mBitmapDrawable); it says that the setImageMatrix is not applicable :( what is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that maybe what you were looking for?

```
tapimageview.setImageBitmap(mBitmapDrawable.getBitmap());
```

Comment: is it possible to make the save image as the new background so that when I add a new image it will be combined with the previously added image? Please help me again, thank you :)

Comment: How to put another image on the saved bitmap? please help please?  @donfuxx

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? I am not sure what you mean with combining images.

Comment: here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917657/how-to-put-another-image-on-the-saved-bitmap please see it, i really dont know what to do about this canvas :( @donfuxx